# cronjob is not working as expected

Tags: scripts, cron

I have scheduled a cronjob to be executed at some time this is the output of the command `contab -l`

```
30 12 * * * /ora/oss/OSS80/DB_DIR/bnsbvt/nimetn/importModifiedServices.sh
```

after a successful execution of the script `importModifiedServices.sh` a csv file should be created at the very same location where the .sh file is. But I am not getting .csv file at the location.
If i execute the script `importModifiedServices.sh` directly by `./importModifiedServices.sh`, the .csv file is being created at that location.
I am not sure what to do now. The shell script has the permission 777.

Comment: Could you post the contents of your script?

Comment: script is just calling a packages that is deployed on that environment. If I am executing the ./sh directly I am getting a csv files generated, btw this is the code.
`sqlplus -s username/password@envSID <<EOF
exec schemaNmae.packageName.procName
exit;
EOF
`

Comment: Is the script creating the file with an absolute path or a relative path?

Comment: @PieterDePraetere I created a db directory and then using that object(db dir) in my package to get the file generated. So you are saying may be the script is being executed but there is some issue while creating the csv file..?

Comment: Look in /var/log/syslog for lines with `[CRON]` e.g. `grep CRON /var/log/syslog`. Maybe this will show some error messages

Comment: `sqlplus` is probably not in the path used by scripts that are called by cron (usuallly only `/usr/bin:/bin`). Find out where sqlplus is located ( `which sqlplus` ) and call it using the absolute path in your script.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see anythong wrong with your crontab entry, so it is probably the script that is malfunctioning.

It looks like the script is creating a file in a relative location (e.g. `./filename.csv`) and this could be the issue. If you execute the script from the directory it is in (`./importModifiedServices.sh`), the relative path is equal to the path the script is in.

If you change the code to use an absolute path (`/ora/oss/OSS80/DB_DIR/bnsbvt/nimetn/`) it will probably work.